# git don't clear development.sqlite3 when I reset to previous commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I start with a fresh rails project: `rails new example`.

Everything goes good and a new project is created with no errors. Mint 19.1, ruby 2.5.7, rails 6.0.1 and the default sqlite3 database.

First thing I make a commit:
`git add -A`
`git commit -m fresh`.
So far so good.

Then I create a simple model:
`rails generate model someModel key1:string key2:string`
`rails db:migrate`

And here something goes wrong big time !

the command `git status` returns this output:

`On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    app/models/some_model.rb
    db/migrate/
    db/schema.rb
    test/fixtures/some_models.yml
    test/models/some_model_test.rb
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`

But what about development.sqlite3 ??

The file was created during the migration and git seems to ignore it. The outcome is that development.sqlite3 will exist for all branches and commits.

If I do hard reset back to HEAD and `git clean -fd` the model, schema and migrate files are gone as expected but development.sqlite3 is still there !

Either I found a terrible bug with git or I do something wrong.

Comment: What is the content of `.gitignore`... _and_ what does `git status --ignored` show?

Comment: yea. I got it. /db/*.sqlite3 was there by default and I had no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
/db/*.sqlite3 was in .gitignore by default.